# Web api with 2 pipelines and a different authentication for each one

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

I am developing a Web Api that contains 2 endpoints A and B and I need to use BasicAuthentication for A and a custom validation for B. I am trying not split the code in 2 projects and for that I am using OWIN with 2 pipe:

```
        app.Map("/api/A", basicAuth =>
        {                
            basicAuth.UseBasicAuthentication(container);
        });

        app.Map("/api/B", idTokenAuth =>
        {                
            idTokenAuth.UseBearerAuthentication(container);
        });
```

The problem I am experiencing is that after the authentication it doesn't redirect to the corresponding controller and returns always HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

Any tip?

Comment: I found this to be useful when working with multiple pipelines--[check this article](http://www.strathweb.com/2016/05/running-multiple-asp-net-web-api-pipelines-side-by-side/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume after this you have app.UseWebApi? The trouble with using Map here is that it doesn't rejoin the parent pipeline when it's done (though it will fall through to IIS/MVC). Here's an analogy...

You want is:

`if (path.startswith("/api/a"))
{
  DoBasicAuth(optionsA);
}
if (path.startswith("/api/b"))
{
  DoBasicAuth(optionsB);
}
DoWebApi();`

But what Map actually does is:

`if (path.startswith("/api/a"))
{
  DoBasicAuth(optionsA);
  return;
}
if (path.startswith("/api/b"))
{
  DoBasicAuth(optionsB);
  return;
}
DoWebApi();`

We've since come up with a different UseWhen pattern you can follow, but you'll have to copy the source and back-port it:
https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseWhenExtensions.cs

Comment: You are right, that's exactly my problem, the return! I didn't manage to make it work with the examples from the links, but I also read more about how owin works. For the purpose of what I want (2 auth methods), I can implement 2 auth methods and add them to the same pipeline and using passive AuthMode I am able to handle the requests, but I miss again the redirect to the controller!